# Serialization error occurs when using TempData in my action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use tempdata to pass data to another action method, but the following error occurs when the page is rendered:

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' 
>       mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result 
>       non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The 
>       same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom 
>       session state store in 'Custom' mode.

This is my initial action

```
 public ActionResult Request(string id)
 {
     viewmodelservice = obj = new viewmodelservice ();
     obj.list = getlist(); 
     TempData["VmList"] = obj.list;
     return View(requestBackUpScheduleVMViewModelObj);
 }
```

And here is the additional action where I am retrieving the value from TempData

```
 public ActionResult getRequest(string id,[DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
     viewmodelservice = obj = new viewmodelservice ();
     obj = (viewmodelservice )TempData["VmList"]
     return json(obj.ToDataSourceResult(request));
 }
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the class you are serializaing as `[Serializable]` (and make sure that it is...). That is whatever class `obj.getlist` returns.

If `obj.getlist()` returns a `List<MyClass>` then `MyClass` needs to have the attribute applied

TempData uses session under the hood, and if you are using a remote/shared session state eg Redis or SqlServer then all items that you store in session will need to be marked so.

Comment: yes we are using a remote session with sqlserver . I declared my class as [Serializable] but the error remains the same ..

Comment: Are there any nested classes or framework classes that are not serializable? Can you post the class for `getlist`?

Comment: Thanks ..  it worked actually i was using a viewmodel and all the classes in viewModel have to be [Serializable] .